# unable to update table specific row

Tags: php, sql, row

I had been trying many methods to update a specific row in my sql data base named `juytdb` having table `users` having colum names `username` and `email`. First I tried to connect and connection was successfull,

```
$localhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "google";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "juytdb";



$connect = mysql_connect($localhost ,$dbuser ,$dbpass);

mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect);
```

Now while I wanted to update a specific row I used

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['var']; //acutally users are logged so I just need to add their email

$email = $_POST['email']; //value I got from an inputbox


    UPDATE users
SET email='google@gmail.com';
WHERE username='billy';
```

this does not work, I also tried

```
$sql = "UPDATE 'users' SET 'email' = '$email' WHERE 'username' = '$username'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

additionally the default values of email is set to "`not added`"

Comment: So many things wrong with that code. First off, don't use mysql_* functions anymore, use mysqli_* or PDO. After that, look at some basic SQL examples. Columns can be surrounded by ``` or not, while strings must be surrounded by `'` or `"`. And don't forget that you should escape data before using it in queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotes where you should have backquotes.  Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = '$email' WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET email = '".$email."' WHERE username = ".$username;
```

Comment: This won't work :) Strings should be surrounded by `'` or `"`